# Parsing json output into lists of multiple types using RestEasy and Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, resteasy

I am writing RestEasy Client API and the output is like this

API A returns { "obj_a_list" : [ objects of A ] }
API B returns { "obj_b_list" : [ objects of B ] }

I am trying to write a generic class

```
import java.util.List;

class ListOfList<T> {

    public ListOfList () {}

    public List<T> getList() {
        return theList;
    }

    public void setList(List<T> theList) {
        this.theList = theList;
    }

    private List<T> theList;

} // ListOfList
```

Is it possible to have dynamic annotation @JsonProperty("obj_a_list") or  @JsonProperty("obj_b_list") on theList property?

so that it can be parsed as

```
ListOfList<A> lol = response.readEntity(new GenericType<ListOfList<A>>(){});
List<A> la = lol.getList();
```

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently using this workaround.

```
/*
        jsonString format could be
        { "A" : [ Array of A ] } OR
        { "B" : [ Array of B ] } OR
        { "C" : [ Array of C ] }

     */
    public static <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz, String jsonString, String arrayName) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<T> retVal = new ArrayList<T>();

        try {
            Map<String, List<T>> userData = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);

            List<T> l = userData.get(arrayName);

            for (T a: l) {
                retVal.add(mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(a), clazz));
            } // for


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retVal;

    }
```